# How to use routerLinkActive with activated mat-nav-list

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have been trying to use the easiest way to put some links into the page.

Firstly, I could not find out how to make a list of links like [what doc said](https://material.angular.io/components/list/overview). There is no example for it. Like this:

```
<mat-nav-list>
  <a mat-list-item href="..." *ngFor="let link of links" [activated]="link.isActive">{{ link }}</a>
</mat-nav-list>
```

Feels like it's coming from the routes defined somewhere given the `isActive` property seems quite revealing.

I just want to make up my own lists. yet the doc using `[activated]` field when there is no such thing in the `routerLinkActive` approach.

After some playing, it seems `Angular Material` using this class `mdc-list-item--activated` for the active state.

So finally I write code like this. But I don't think this is a good way. Even though it display as expected.

```
<mat-nav-list>
    <a mat-list-item routerLink="/admin/dashboard" routerLinkActive="mdc-list-item--activated">Dashboard</a>
    <a mat-list-item routerLink="/admin/lines" routerLinkActive="mdc-list-item--activated">Lines</a>
    <a mat-list-item routerLink="/admin/users" routerLinkActive="mdc-list-item--activated">Users</a>
</mat-nav-list>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `[activated]` property is simple true or false. You're right, the route `isActive` in the items is simple a bool like this:

```
items = [ { isActive: false, link: "Home" }, .... ]
```

If you click on a item, set the current items `isActive` to true - done.

But to use `routerLinkActive` is absolutely ok, too!

#### What is the different?

`activated` will enable the **Material List Item Style**. So a style for this item created by material with design colors and so on.

`routerLinkActive` will set **your** custom style if the link is active.

Short: Both ways are ok.

Comment: So that link object is some kind of angular routes, not a normal object. What is it? Because it should update isActive with the active route I would guess. There is no way I have to detect the current route and toggle isActive myself I think

Comment: You can with the `Router`. console.log(this.router.url);